# Start a function after another is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

In the menu of the website, I was using setTimeout, to wait for the animation to end in order to move to another page like this:

```
$('.carousel .item').click(function(e) {
        var index = $(this).index('li');
        carousel.cycleActiveTo(index);
        // song3();
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( currentIndex != index ){
            var difference;

            if ( currentIndex == 0 && index >= 5 ){
                difference = (index - currentIndex) - 13;
            } else {
                difference = index - currentIndex;
            }

            difference = Math.abs(difference);
            delay = difference * options.duration;
            currentIndex = index;

            console.log(delay);

            setTimeout( goToLink, delay );
        } else {
                goToLink();
        }
    });
```

However now, I'm using a page transition which takes care of redirection. I'm calling the page transition function within the setTimeout instead of goToLink, but for some reason it doesn't wait for the animation to be finished and goes directly to the transition.. does anyone have ideas?

this is the transition library that I'm using, https://github.com/icodebuster/transition.js

and this is my website, for the moment i enabled the transition only for the About section 
http://stfn.herokuapp.com

Comment: You need `e.stopPropagation()` too

Answer (score 0):

When animation time is finished call a function which can redirect you to your desired page

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But am I not doing it already with the setTimeout?

Comment: In your code i think you program always call else. See is your code found true for if condition